# How to execute this curl command with c# - http post with image and parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, curl, http-post

I am trying to upload my images to deviantart

They give below curl command as example to upload stash

I got my access_token already however i don't know how can i post this with either using asp.net or C#

Help is appreciated

I need to upload image along with parameters

Here the curl command they gave as example

```
 curl https://www.deviantart.com/api/v1/oauth2/stash/submit \
-F "title=My great stash item&artist_comments=This is a great image&keywords=test image" \
-F access_token=Alph4num3r1ct0k3nv4lu3 \
-F "test=@path/to/image.png"
```

c# .net 4.5

Answer (score 1):

You can send a `POST` request using `WebClient` like following.

```
using (var webcl = new WebClient())
{
    var inputdata = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
    inputdata["title"] = "My great stash item";
    inputdata["artist_comments"] = "This is a great image";
    inputdata["keywords"] = "test image";
    inputdata["access_token"] = "Alph4num3r1ct0k3nv4lu3";
    inputdata["test"] = "path/to/image";

    var output = webcl.UploadValues("https://www.deviantart.com/api/v1/oauth2/stash/submit", "POST", inputdata);
}
```

However, when i tried this, I got `401 unauthorized error`. Might be `access_token` got expired.

Because when i tried samething with `curl`,i also got following error.

> {"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Expired oAuth2 user
>   token. The cli ent should request a new one with an access code or a
>   refresh token.","status":" error"}

Comment: ty very much gonna try yes it requires access token :D

Comment: ok this failed. because i am supposed to post image data as well. this doesn't post image ? it says 400 bad request . that test parameter need to be image

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG, can you try using some publicly hosted image path there, like ` inputdata["test"] = "https ://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/i1_71651352.png"`.

Comment: well publicly hosted would not work for me i have to upload from my computer 1000+ images. with free curl this job is super easy but i am shocked .net does not have proper handling classes